# Update To Target Schema Compare Visual Studio Just Hangs

Tags: visual-studio, database-project

In Visual Studio 2019, when I update the visual studio project form the schema compare tool it just hangs. Its not like its a lot of objects being updated either. I tried googling the issue and most people are having issues with just the compare part of the issue, not the update part.

Image not really helpful but its been like this for 8 hours:

[image]

Comment: What happens if you generate a script instead of trying to update your target?

Comment: I ended up nuking the project and repulling down from git and it seemed to fix the issue.